# Kawasaki EX400 2012 cold stalling

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-injection, stall, kawasaki

I got a efi motocycle that stalls when cold at stop lights.

It only happens if 4-5k rpm was reached before pulling the clutch.

When it doesn't stall I notice very low rpm.

Cold starts are iffy. It starts at very low rpm and sometime I have to give it throttle to start it. Hot starts are fine.

Problem goes away completly after 5-10 min.

Dealer looked at it and changed broken throttle bodys.

Did not solved the issue.

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I'm guessing he checked the air filter? When is valve clearance due, and has it been done on time?

Comment: Valve clearance is due in about 12k, air filter have been cleaned up 500 km ago.

Comment: And idle is normal after it warms up?

Comment: Yes, generaly after three stop down a neighbourhood. It seems to only stall while in gear, I suspect a sticky clutch or a sensor issue. I will try to start it in gear to see if it has the same issue.

Comment: I ruled out the clutch, if I go 20 kmh, pull the clutch and release the throttle when cold, it stalls. I called the dealer they asked me to bring it back.